# Twitter services automatization

Tags: java, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to simulate user behaviour on some twitter service that use oauth autorization(you have to enter your twiter credentials and allow to application access to it)?

For example, I have some routine actions with couple of twitter accounts on some twitter service and wanted to write a program(java\python etc.) to make it automatically.
Is there any way to login in such services?

Comment: You probably want to clarify what exactly you are trying to do, as from what you wrote, most people will think that you trying to feed fake/spam accounts and won't give you good answers.

Comment: I don't know in java but i coded this program https://github.com/elpeter/pv-auto-tweets/blob/master/index.php it's really simple, and i am using it with a cronjob and it's totaly automatic and unattended. I don't know if it's what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible ton automatize application authorization using username and password. You need to "simulate" user acceptation (on the auth web page) and parse the PIN code on the resulting page.

You need username and password (or manual acceptation) one time only if you retrieve and save user tokens (key and secret).

Some OAuth libs already provide such features